# Is there a way to edit information in an open apk activity

Tags: android, apk, inspect

So i have an apk that's shows some info like name and phone number, i was wondering if there is a way to edit this info when the app is opened in the phone, something like the developer tools in the browser where u can edit any text from the inspect page, so is there something like that for Android apps?

Comment: You may be able to manipulate apps using Frida or Xposed but that requires a rooted phone. Using Frida's gadget it would be possible on a regular phone but then the app to be modified has to be modified by adding Frida gadget to the APK (and then re-signing the APK).

Comment: I think that might work, i will try it